# How does an &&, || work with jenkins pipeline groovy?

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I tried the below OR (||) to mark the build fail if any of the myTeststring1 OR myTeststring2 matches the console output. I tried few other ways with ||, it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

```
if (manager.logContains('.myTestString1.') || ('.myTestString2.')) { 
error("Build failed because of this and that..") 
}
```

I am trying to match two or more patterns to the Jenkins console output to mark build failure.

Answer (score 1):

try the below... after the OR you need to provide an expression, in your example you didn't

```
  if (manager.logContains('.myTestString1.') || 
    manager.logContains('.myTestString2.')) { 
  error("Build failed because of this and that..") 
  }
```

Comment: kbry, that doesn't work either, Unexpected token || is the error. Similar approaches I tried but failed.

Comment: Are you using declarative or scripted pipeline? Can you share it ( without stuff like keys and urls :) )